# Renaming a file sequence

Tags: python, rename

I have the following folder structure

```
folder1/
    file1a.txt
    file1b.txt
    file1c.txt
    file2a.txt
    file2b.txt
    file2c.txt
    file3a.txt
    file3b.txt
    file3c.txt
    file4a.txt
    file4b.txt
    file4c.txt
    file5a.txt
    file5b.txt
    file5c.txt

folder2/
    file1a.txt
    file1b.txt
    file1c.txt
    file2a.txt
    file2b.txt
    file2c.txt
    file3a.txt
    file3b.txt
    file3c.txt
    file4a.txt
    file4b.txt
    file4c.txt
    file5a.txt
    file5b.txt
    file5c.txt
```

I want to rename the files in `folder2` such that they are in sequence with files in `folder1` — i.e.

```
folder2/
    file6a.txt
    file6b.txt
    file6c.txt
    file7a.txt
    file7b.txt
    file7c.txt
    file8a.txt
    file8b.txt
    file8c.txt
    file9a.txt
    file9b.txt
    file9c.txt
    file10a.txt
    file10b.txt
    file10c.txt
```

My strategy is to (pseudo code):

```
1. read in files from folder1
2. make a unique list of those files
3. count the number of files in that unique list
4. set that number to be the starting number for the files to be renamed in folder2 (e.g. 6)
5. count the number of files in folder2 and set that to be the end of the range (e.g. 10)
6. and rename the files in folder2 as shown in the example
```

The step that I am unable to conceive is the repetition of the file name in folder 2 — i.e. `file6a.txt, file6b.txt, file6c.txt`.

In BASH i can run  this:

```
i=1; j=6; rename file${i} file${j} folder2/file${i}*
```

What would the pythonic way of doing this be?

**Edit:** Updated the question to be more accurate and added pseudo-code to illustrate strategy.

Comment: Read the list of files into a single list, sort it, use `enumerate()` to keep track of the index through the list and rename those that start with `folder2/` using that enumeration index.

Comment: Can you pls show what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Hi, I have only managed to read in and count the files in folder1.

Comment: File directories (folders) cannot have two files with the same name in them, so their names will be unique in any list of them (this means that the sample folder structure shown in your question is impossible).

Comment: You are correct martineau... I have updated the question...

Answer (score 0):

You can us os and do this

```
import os
import re
files = os.listdir(PATHTOFOLDER1)
files2 = os.listdir(PATHTOFOLDER2)
lastfile = files[-1]
temp = re.findall(r'\d+', lastfile)[0]

for i in range(int(temp), len(files2)+int(temp)):
         os.rename(PATHTOFOLDER2 + files2[i], PATHTOFOLDER2 + f"file{i}.txt")
```

You can do this and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os, os.path

# simple version for working with CWD
#print (len([name for name in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(name)]))

# path joining version for other paths
DIR = r"folder"
a=print (len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))]))
print(a)
# Python program to rename all file 
# names in your directory 


os.chdir('folder2') 
print(os.getcwd()) 
COUNT = a

# Function to increment count 
# to make the files sorted. 
def increment(): 
    global COUNT 
    COUNT = COUNT + 1


for f in os.listdir(): 
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f) 
    f_name = "foldername" + str(COUNT) 
    increment() 

    new_name = '{} {}'.format(f_name, f_ext) 
    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it...

```
# Change this based on your path
PATH1 = "/path/to/folder1"
PATH1 += "/"

PATH2 = "/path/to/folder2"
PATH2 += "/"

TAG = "file"

files_in_raw1 = os.listdir(PATH1)
files_in_raw2 = os.listdir(PATH2)

unique_files_in_raw1 = []
unique_files_in_raw2 = []


for files1, files2 in zip(files_in_raw1, files_in_raw2):
    # i[:4] gets the file name "file". This var will change based on the tag that needs substitution.
    tag1 = list(os.path.splitext(files1[:4]))[0]
    tag2 = list(os.path.splitext(files2[:4]))[0]
    if tag1 not in unique_files_in_raw1:
        unique_files_in_raw1.append(tag1)
    if tag2 not in unique_files_in_raw2:
        unique_files_in_raw2.append(tag2)

unique_files_in_raw1.sort()
unique_files_in_raw2.sort()

COUNT = len(unique_files_in_raw1)
START = COUNT + 1
END = START + len(unique_files_in_raw2)

continue_naming_files = []
for x in range(START, END):
    continue_naming_files.append(TAG + "0" + str(x))

new_name = []
for file in files_in_raw2:
    for name in continue_naming_files:
        new_file = re.sub(file[:11], name, file)
        new_name.append(new_file)

for i, j in zip(files_in_raw2, new_name):
    os.symlink(PATH2 + i, PATH2 + j)
```